# How to insert node/element in XML using Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, linq-to-xml

I am trying to insert these nodes `price`, `qty`, `amount` under the descendants `Apple` > `Store` only using the attribute to find the exact location of insert.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fruits>
    <node text="Apple" tag="a" imageindex="0">
        <node text="Store" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
        <node text="City" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
    </node>
    <node text="Orange" tag="a" imageindex="0">
        <node text="Store" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
        <node text="City" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
    </node>
</Fruits>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fruits>
    <node text="Apple" tag="a" imageindex="0">
        <node text="Store" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
            <node text="price" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
            <node text="qty" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
            <node text="amount" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
        <node text="City" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
    </node>
    <node text="Orange" tag="a" imageindex="0">
        <node text="Store" tag="b" imageindex="1" />
        <node text="City" tag="c" imageindex="2" />
    </node>
</Fruits>
```

Here's what I have done so far. I am having difficulty defining the `detail` path using the attribute. I know `Linq to XML` has a straight forward approach but couldn't figure out. Though I tried `foreach` but no avail, it gets more complicated at least to me.

```
XElement xFruit = XElement.Load(@"D:\Xml\Fruit.xml");

XElement detail = xFruit...

detail.Add(
    new XElement("price", "$10"),
    new XElement("qty", "10"),
    new XElement("amount", "$100")
);

xFruit.Save(@"D:\Xml\Fruit.xml");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: detail.Add(
    new XAttribute("price", "$10"),
    new XAttribute("qty", "10"),
    new XAttribute("amount", "$100")

Comment: @jdweng thanks for this but the `details` I want it as a node rather than attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an attribute named "text" to define a path to the location for the insert. To make it straightforward to iterate to that location, you could try writing a simple `FindPath` extension that *knows* that the "text" attribute is the one to look for, and then call the extension like this:

```
var detail = xFruit.FindPath(@"Apple\Store");
detail?.Add(
        new XElement("price", "$10"),
        new XElement("qty", "10"),
        new XElement("amount", "$100")
);
```

So in a top-level static class...

```
static class Extensions
{
```

First make an extension to get the value of an attribute if it exists without throwing an exception if it doesn't (the `FindPath` extension will be using this to examine the "text" attribute).

```
    public static bool TryGetAttributeValue(
        this XElement xel,
        string name,
        out string value)
    {
        var attr = xel.Attributes()
            .FirstOrDefault(@try => string.Equals(name, @try.Name.LocalName));
        if (attr == null)
        {
            value = string.Empty;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            value = attr.Value;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

That makes it simple to write the second extension that iterates to find the node at the path if it exists, returning null if it doesn't. (This method takes a more direct route than the `foreach` iteration that you mentioned.)

```
    public static XElement FindPath(
        this XElement xRoot,
        string path)
    {
        XElement xTraverse = xRoot;
        string[] split = path.Split('\\');
        for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            xTraverse =
                xTraverse.Elements()
                .FirstOrDefault(match =>
                    match.TryGetAttributeValue("text", out string value) &&
                    (value == split[i]));
            if (xTraverse == null) break;
        }
        return xTraverse;
    }
}
```

**TESTBENCH**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xFruit = XElement.Parse(source);
    var detail = xFruit.FindPath(@"Apple\Store");
    detail?.Add(
            new XElement("price", "$10"),
            new XElement("qty", "10"),
            new XElement("amount", "$100")
    );
    Console.WriteLine(xFruit.ToString());
}
const string source =
@"<Fruits>
    <node text=""Apple"" tag=""a"" imageindex=""0"">
        <node text = ""Store"" tag=""b"" imageindex=""1"" />
        <node text = ""City"" tag=""c"" imageindex=""2"" />
    </node>
    <node text = ""Orange"" tag=""a"" imageindex=""0"">
        <node text = ""Store"" tag=""b"" imageindex=""1"" />
        <node text = ""City"" tag=""c"" imageindex=""2"" />
    </node>
</Fruits>";
```

This should match the output you're looking for.

[image: console output]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/insert-using-attribute.git) this testbench.

Comment: Wow! You're not only did not solve my problem but you gave me a `class` that I could reuse through out this project. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it!